# I keep getting the error: "Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code"

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to run motion saliency on a video and see the results. However, I keep getting this particular error:(ret, img_sal) = saliency.computeSaliency(gray)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
Here is the code below:

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('vids/test.mp4')
saliency = cv2.saliency.MotionSaliencyBinWangApr2014_create()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
fps = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps)

while True:
    success, frame = vid.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (ret, img_sal) = saliency.computeSaliency(gray)
    saliencyMap = (img_sal * 255).astype('uint8')
    cv2.imshow('Map', saliencyMap)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vid.release()
```

I would also appreciate if any other errors could be pointed out. I'm trying to save the video after applying motion saliency, so any help to that would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you say: `img_sal = saliency.computeSaliency(gray)`?

Comment: No @VC.One. It shows the same error. I've checked the Opencv documentation on Motion Saliency. The syntax is correct and I'm using the updated version, but still it gives me this error